# Save the image made by user in fingerPaint api demos in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Hey guys
I am trying to build a signature task application .
In which the user will create the signature on touch and that bitmap should be saved in the phone.
I have created 2 class files one having the custom view the same as the one in fingerpaint application and calling the view in main.xml file.

In my main application class file i have menu button which on click saves the bitmap in sdcard . The following is the code :-

```
package org.testCircle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class testCircle extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(new customView(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "save").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            //new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
            fingerPaint cv = new fingerPaint(this);
            Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
            cv.draw(canvas);
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), viewBitmap, "title", null);
            Toast.makeText(testCircle.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Custom  View  :-**

```
package org.testCircle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class fingerPaint extends View {
    Paint mPaint;

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private static Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public fingerPaint(Context c) {
        super(c);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    public fingerPaint(Context c , AttributeSet attrs){
        super(c , attrs);
         mPaint = new Paint();
         mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
         mPaint.setDither(true);
         mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
         mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
         mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
         mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
         mPath = new Path();
         mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    public void onerase(){
        mCanvas=null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, mPaint);

    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: that i can not save the image which contains the signature of the user through touch ; but i can save the initial image which contains only the background and  not the signature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the source code to do that

```
LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
// this is the important code :)
// Without it the view will have a
// dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will
// be null
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
v.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
if (bm != null) {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "screentest.jpg");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        Log.e("ImagePath", "Image Path : " + MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage( getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName()));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code; this is the max i have got far with this project... code is working fine but boss the thing is that when i save the image from my emulator the image is cut in half vertically and the left half is only saved.. i am running on 2.2 and 480X800 emulator

Answer (score 0):

You've got a Bitmap object in your fingerPaint class.  Instantiate a FileOutputStream to the location you'd like to save to, and call mBitmap.compress method with the appropriate options and your output stream.  Remember to close your stream.

Comment: Sorry; but i am able to save the image, but only the background image which is there in the beginning i can not save the updated image which will be done by the user who signs on it

Comment: Looks like you're saving the wrong Bitmap.  I don't think you need any of that extra stuff in onOptionsItemSelected.  After the drawing is complete, you need to save the Bitmap that the drawing was done on (fingerPaint.mBitmap).  You're just instantiating a new blank Bitmap and saving it.

Comment: ok now i am writing this code in on options menu selected :- Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fingerPaint.mBitmap);
         cv.draw(canvas);
         String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), viewBitmap, "title", null);
         Toast.makeText(testCircle.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;                                                                   But now i am getting a plain blank screen and not even the dray background

Answer (score 0):

```
    final View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutFP);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();
           content.invalidate(); 
           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);                          
    }
```

Finally add permission in your Manifest file:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />