# Saving android canvas as a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to save the canvas object in onDraw() method to be saved as a bitmap. Please do not suggest answers like  "view.getDrawingCache(true)" .I want to save canvas directly to a bitmap

Comment: "I want to save the canvas object in onDraw() method to be saved as a bitmap" -- that does not make much sense to me. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442610/how-to-save-the-image-from-canvas-code-in-android-application

Comment: what's wrong with getDrawingCache()?  That works just fine for me when I need to grab a view's visible assets.   But if you really want the entire canvas, see my answer below

Comment: @Martin : Thanks for the reply, i will check that.

Comment: @Commonsware : i am performing some animation on canvas, and then i want to save that animation as a squence of bitmaps in my sdcard, and finally i am converting those images to video via ffmpeg... I have acheived to get the squence of bitmaps with a rate of 4 bitmaps per second, But i want more bitmaps per second (prefrably 8 fps). Hope you understood what i am trying to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

```
// first create a mutable bitmap - you determine the size
bkg = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// create a canvas with that empty bitmap
Canvas c = new Canvas(bkg);

// do whatever drawing methoods you need....I did a circle
c.drawColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.off_white));
p.setColor(pixel);
c.drawCircle(width / 2, width / 2, width / 2, p);

// then pull off the entire canvas as a bitmapdrawable (or bitmap, if you perfer)
return new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bkg);
```