# How to change the color of a touched region in ImageView?

Tags: android, colors, imageview, android-resources, ontouchlistener

I need to set white color to the region that the user touches on an ImageView. If I setOnTouchListener to the ImageView and get the x and y positions of the touch, how can I change the appropriate pixel values in the ImageView? or is there a better solution?

Comment: use `getImageMatrix` and read **carefully** `Matrix` API

Comment: Look at http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/ example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to extend `ImageView`.

Here is a brief example that draws a black circle around touched area:

```
class TouchableImageView extends ImageView {
    private float x, y;
    private Paint paint;

    public TouchableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TouchableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TouchableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TouchableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        invalidate();
      }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Just for example - draw a circle around touch area:
        if(x!=0 || y!=0)
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

If you want to save the result as a bitmap - you need several more steps as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294764/saving-android-canvas-as-a-bitmap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14726271/3349800).

In short you should follow these steps :

1. Create a new Bitmap of the required size
2. Create new canvas for the created Bitmap - `new Canvas(bitmap)`
3. Re-draw all you need upon this canvas
4. Save bitmap as a graphics file

Comment: Thanks, your example was usefull, but on every touch it deletes previous drawing, how it can be saved? I am trying to implemet smth like rubber during onTouch.

Comment: Just store arrays of x and y (like in ArrayList<Float>) and draw them in onDraw() in a cycle. You may need to use not only MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, but also ACTION_MOVE to remember where and how user moved his finger (but remember there may be very many such events)

Comment: I need to change pixels of my source image