# How to save the drawing in canvas and Frame Layout with background

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I'm trying to save my drawing into Canvas and Framelayout with a background on it, i was able to save the Canvas and it's drawing but the Problem is the FrameLayout. It seems that my code is only saving the canvas not the Framelayout (background image).  Can anyone help me with this.

```
public class Draw extends Activity implements {


    public static String filex;

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    public static String selectedImagePath;
    public static Bitmap cBitmap;

    public static Integer resize;
    public static Integer imageBackgroundEraser;
    // Instance variables

    public static Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;
    private MyView      mView;
    private int mImageCount = 0;
    private int mLastBg = 0;

    public static Integer WW;
    public static Integer WH;

    private float BrushWidth; 
    private int  thickness;
    private int BrushColor;
    public static int backgroundColor; 
    float Mx1,My1;
    float x,y;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); //***


        final MyView myView = new MyView(this);
        FrameLayout frm_layout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
        frm_layout.addView(myView);
        Drawable x = Drawable.createFromPath(selectedImagePath)
        frm_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(x);
        frm_layout.addView(myView);

        setInitialPaint();

    }

    private void setInitialPaint() {
        //bgColor = 0xFFFFFFFF; // default bg color white
        BrushWidth = 3;
        BrushColor = 0xFF000000; //**
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(BrushColor);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BrushWidth);
        mPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30) );
        //mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        //mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.saveBtn:
            File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Pictures/Draw");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); //***
            String fname = timeStamp + ".png";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            System.out.println(file+"----> file");
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            saveAsPng(file);
        break;


        }
    }

    public void saveAsPng (File f)
    {
        String fname = f.getAbsolutePath ();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream (f);
            mView.mBitmap.compress (CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);  
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "Saved " + fname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
          Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + ex.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
          ex.printStackTrace ();
        }

    } // end saveAsPng

    } // end Main

    public class MyView extends View {

    // Constants and variables
        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        public static Bitmap  mBitmap;
        public static Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        private  Bitmap cBitmap;
        private Canvas  xCanvas;
        private  Bitmap xBitmap;



        public MyView(Context c) 
        {
            super(c);


                // Figure out how this works. Seems odd that we set up a canvas and a bitmap. 
                // I don't see how it connects to what shows on screen.    
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Draw4FunMain.WW, Draw4FunMain.WH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                mPath = new Path();
                mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
                // mCanvas.setBackgroundResource(0xFFFFFFFF);
                if (Draw4FunMain.imageBackgroundEraser == null) {
                    mCanvas.drawColor (Color.WHITE);
                } else {

                    mCanvas.drawColor (Color.TRANSPARENT); 
                }

        }

        public MyView (Context c, int color)
        {
            super(c);

                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Draw4FunMain.WW, Draw4FunMain.WH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                mPath = new Path();
                mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
                mCanvas.drawColor (color);
                //Draw4FunMain.backgroundColor  = color;
        }

    /**
     */
    // Methods

    /**
     */
    @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    /**
     */
    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {

            //canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, Draw4FunMain.mPaint);

    }

    /**
     */
        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    /**
     */
        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    /**
     */
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
    /**
     */
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, Draw4FunMain.mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

    /**
     */

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    } // end MyView
```

Answer (score 0):

That the background image you set for FrameLayout is not saved is because you didn't draw it on the bitmap you are trying to save.

There's an easy way of doing what you want, you simply take a screenshot of the FrameLayout, so that anything inside the FrameLayout will be captured, and save that screenshot as raw bytes to file.

```
frameLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = frameLayout.getDrawingCache();
bitmap.compress (CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

Comment: thanks neevek i got it.  it's almost same as this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029775/save-the-image-made-by-user-in-fingerpaint-api-demos-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @Aid, if that solves your problem, please mark it as the answer.