# How to save bitmap to png/jpg file with text added

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to display an image in a canvas, add some text and save the Bitmap to png/jpg file.
in the future I want to get the text from an EditText and the user will be able to add the text in the position He wants, this is the reason why I want to display the image.

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c)
        {

     Paint paint=new Paint();
     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);                        
     c.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 50, 50, paint);         

     c.drawText("hello", 100, 100, paint);                  

        }
```

If I want to save myBitmap to png file I have:

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.png";
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

 myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
stream.close();
```

but I'm getting the image  without the text added

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Save The Image From Canvas code in Android Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442610/how-to-save-the-image-from-canvas-code-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not saving the Canvas itself.

See also:

- [Save the image made by user in fingerPaint api demos in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029775/save-the-image-made-by-user-in-fingerpaint-api-demos-in-android)
- [How to Save The Image From Canvas code in Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442610/how-to-save-the-image-from-canvas-code-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to utilise the Canvas constructor where you pass the Bitmap as a parameter to the constructor, so when the Canvas gets drawn to, it effectively draws to the given Bitmap.